# Oracle 11.1.0 Autobackup going to wrong location

Tags: oracle-11g, rman

I am running Oracle 11.1.0 on Win Server 2008. My autobackups used to go to flash_recovery_area\myDB\autobackup\*yyyy_mm_dd*. Then I added a prefix to the file name in front of %F and they started going to C:\ORACLE\PRODUCT\11.1.0\DB_1\DATABASE\ so I removed the prefix but they still don't go to the flash recovery area. I realize I could specify the directory but I would prefer if it went back to putting each backup in its own folder with the date. I didn't make any other changes, any ideas what I am doing wrong? My RMAN config output is:

```
using target database control file instead of recovery catalog
RMAN configuration parameters for database with db_unique_name SPATIAL are:
CONFIGURE RETENTION POLICY TO RECOVERY WINDOW OF 31 DAYS;
CONFIGURE BACKUP OPTIMIZATION ON;
CONFIGURE DEFAULT DEVICE TYPE TO DISK; # default
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP ON;
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP FORMAT FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO '%F';
CONFIGURE DEVICE TYPE DISK PARALLELISM 1 BACKUP TYPE TO BACKUPSET; # default
CONFIGURE DATAFILE BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO 1; # default
CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO 1; # default
CONFIGURE MAXSETSIZE TO UNLIMITED; # default
CONFIGURE ENCRYPTION FOR DATABASE OFF; # default
CONFIGURE ENCRYPTION ALGORITHM 'AES128'; # default
CONFIGURE COMPRESSION ALGORITHM 'BZIP2'; # default
CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG DELETION POLICY TO NONE; # default
CONFIGURE SNAPSHOT CONTROLFILE NAME TO 'C:\ORACLE\PRODUCT\11.1.0\DB_1\DATABASE\SNCFSPATIAL.ORA'; # default
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured out the problem. Simply changing the Autobackup Format back to the default '%F' is not viewed as the default. In order to truly have the default value you must use the clear command.

```
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP FORMAT FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK CLEAR;
```

RMAN behaivor returned to normal. Thanks to all who viewed my question!

Answer (score 0):

If we don't set using CLEAR,below will be output
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP FORMAT FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO '%F';

If we set using clear,then output is below:

CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP FORMAT FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO '%F'; # default

observer the # default keyword.